# Android Json parsing is getting error

Tags: java, android, json

In my Android application ..I am using json to connect with server for displaying values.. data is saved inside the server..I am getting result when the value is an integer like 1,2,3 .. and I am able to get the result also... but when I tried to get the value of char like A,B,C like that I am not getting the result... I am giving the code.. please check and if there is any error please help.

Class

```
String pid,number, heartnumber,personalitynumber,men,mhdnumber,mpnumber,chnum,pinnum,costone,custone,fvowel,lieno,hrpeno,exheno,rthno,pyno,pmnno,pdyno,scno,blno;    
TextView txtName, txtName1, txtName2,txtName3,txtName4,txtName5,txtName6,txtName7,txtName8,txtName9,txtName10,txtName11,txtName12,txtName13,txtName14,txtName15,txtName16,txtName17,txtName18,txtName19,txtName20;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String url_cup_stone= "http://iascpl.com/app/get_cup_stone.php";
private static final String url_first_vowel= "http://iascpl.com/app/get_first_vowel.php";

private static final String TAG_CORNERSTONE = "cornerstone";
private static final String TAG_CUPSTONE = "cupstone";
TextView txt27 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView48);
txt27.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("aChar"));
TextView txt28 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView51);
txt28.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("aChar1"));

costone = txt27.getText().toString();
custone = txt28.getText().toString();

new GetProductDetails().execute();

class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FullExplanation.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading the result... Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)     
    {

        TextView txt27 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView48);
        TextView txt28 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView51);

        costone = txt27.getText().toString();

        custone = txt28.getText().toString();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("costone", costone));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("custone", custone));

        JSONObject json9 = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_corner_stone, "GET", params);

        JSONObject json10 = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_cup_stone, "GET", params);

        Log.d("Single Product Details", json9.toString());
        Log.d("Single Product Details", json10.toString());

        int success9 = json9.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        int success10 = json10.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success9 == 1) {
            // successfully received product details
            JSONArray productObj = json9
                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

            // get first product object from JSON Array
            final JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

            // product with this pid found
            // Edit Text

            txtName9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView49);


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {

                        txtName9.setText(product.getString(TAG_CORNERSTONE));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        }else{
            // product with pid not found

        }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

Logcat

```
58:00.251: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:01.021: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 200 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:01.851: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:02.231: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:03.751: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:03.971: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:04.331: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:04.491: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:04.641: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:04.851: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:05.141: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:05.391: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:05.791: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:05.931: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:06.341: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 105 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:06.531: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:06.791: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:07.051: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:07.301: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:07.521: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:07.651: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:08.721: D/dalvikvm(5133): GC_CONCURRENT freed 251K, 9% free 4257K/4632K, paused 77ms+14ms, total 199ms
12-11 08:58:12.631: D/dalvikvm(5133): GC_CONCURRENT freed 405K, 11% free 4374K/4900K, paused 76ms+89ms, total 280ms
12-11 08:58:16.161: D/dalvikvm(5133): GC_CONCURRENT freed 545K, 14% free 4373K/5040K, paused 77ms+89ms, total 326ms
12-11 08:58:16.772: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"created_at":"2013-11-04 02:43:45","number":null,"pid":"1","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","description":"This is the prediction for destiny number 1."}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:16.772: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"created_at":"2013-11-04 02:45:57","talent":"This is the prediction for talent number 8.","number":"8","pid":"8","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","description":"This is the prediction for destiny number 8."}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:16.811: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"heartnumber":"5","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","heart":"This is the prediction for heart number 5.","description":"This is the prediction for destiny number 5.","created_at":"2013-11-04 02:45:22","talent":"This is the prediction for talent number 5.","number":"5","pid":"5"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:16.841: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"created_at":"2013-11-11 22:24:52","pid":"5","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","personality":"This is the prediction for Personality Number 5.","personalitynumber":"5"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:16.871: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"created_at":"2013-11-11 22:28:18","menp":"This is the prediction for Minor Expression Number 11.","pid":"11","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","men":"11","personality":"This is the prediction for Personality Number 11.","personalitynumber":"11"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:16.911: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"menp":"This is the prediction for Minor Expression Number 1.","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","created_at":"2013-11-11 22:19:51","pid":"1","men":"1","mhd":"This is the prediction for Minor Heart Desire Number 1.","personality":"This is the prediction for Personality Number 1.","mhdnumber":"1","personalitynumber":"1"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:16.941: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"menp":"This is the prediction for Minor Expression Number 1.","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","created_at":"2013-11-11 22:19:51","pid":"1","mpnumber":"1","men":"1","mpn":"This is the prediction for Minor Personality Number 1.","mhd":"This is the prediction for Minor Heart Desire Number 1.","personality":"This is the prediction for Personality Number 1.","mhdnumber":"1","personalitynumber":"1"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:16.981: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"pinnacle":"This is the prediction for the Pinnacle Number 1","created_at":"2013-11-23 03:05:21","pid":"1","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","challenge":"This is the prediction for Challenge number 1.","pinnum":"1","chnum":"1"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:17.003: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"pinnacle":"This is the prediction for Pinnacle Number 5.","created_at":"2013-11-23 03:08:57","pid":"5","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","challenge":"This is the prediction for Challenge Number 5.","pinnum":"5","chnum":"5"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:17.012: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"message":"No product found","success":0}
12-11 08:58:17.025: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"message":"No product found","success":0}
12-11 08:58:17.061: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"message":"No product found","success":0}
12-11 08:58:17.091: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"lieno":"7","hrpeno":"7","heartpersonality":"This is the prediction for Heart Desire\/Expression Bridge number 7.","lifepathexpression":"This is the prediction for LifePath\/Expression Bridge number 7.","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","expressionheart":"This is the prediction for Heart Desire\/Expression Bridge number 7.","created_at":"2013-11-27 01:07:06","pid":"8","exheno":"7"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:17.121: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"lieno":"0","hrpeno":"0","heartpersonality":"This is the prediction for Heart Desire\/Personality Bridge number 0.","lifepathexpression":"This is the prediction for Life Path\/Expression Bridge number 0.","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","expressionheart":"This is the prediction for Heart Desire\/Expression Bridge number 0.","created_at":"2013-11-27 01:01:20","pid":"1","exheno":"0"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:17.161: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"lieno":"4","hrpeno":"4","heartpersonality":"This is the prediction for Heart Desire\/Personality Bridge number 4.","lifepathexpression":"This is the prediction for LifePath\/Expression Bridge number 4.","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","expressionheart":"This is the prediction for Heart Desire\/Expression Bridge number 4.","created_at":"2013-11-27 01:05:27","pid":"5","exheno":"4"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:17.201: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","pyno":"5","pdyno":"5","pmnno":"5","pdaynumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Day Number 5.","pmonthnumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Month Number 5.","pyearnumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Year Number 5.","created_at":"2013-11-28 01:16:49","rthoughtnumber":"This is the prediction for Relational Thought Number 5.","pid":"5","rthno":"5"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:17.231: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","pyno":"11","pdyno":"11","pmnno":"11","pdaynumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Day Number 11.","pmonthnumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Month Number 11.","pyearnumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Year Number 11.","created_at":"2013-11-28 01:23:11","rthoughtnumber":"This is the prediction for Relational Thought Number 11.","pid":"10","rthno":"11"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:17.262: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","pyno":"5","pdyno":"5","pmnno":"5","pdaynumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Day Number 5.","pmonthnumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Month Number 5.","pyearnumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Year Number 5.","created_at":"2013-11-28 01:16:49","rthoughtnumber":"This is the prediction for Relational Thought Number 5.","pid":"5","rthno":"5"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:17.291: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","pyno":"7","pdyno":"7","pmnno":"7","pdaynumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Day Number 7.","pmonthnumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Month Number 7.","pyearnumber":"This is the prediction for Personal Year Number 7.","created_at":"2013-11-28 01:18:33","rthoughtnumber":"This is the prediction for Relational Thought Number 7.","pid":"7","rthno":"7"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:17.301: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"balance":"This is the prediction for the Balance Number 1.","karmic":"This is the prediction for the Karmic Lesson 1.","klno":"1","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","blno":"1","created_at":"2013-11-29 04:17:10","pid":"1","scno":"1","subconcious":"This is the prediction for the Sub-Concious Self 1.","hiddenpassion":"This is the prediction for the Hidden Passion 1.","hpno":"1"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:17.321: D/Single Product Details(5133): {"product":[{"balance":"This is the prediction for the Balance Number 3.","karmic":"This is the prediction for the Karmic Lesson 3.","klno":"3","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","blno":"3","created_at":"2013-11-29 04:19:31","pid":"3","scno":"3","subconcious":"This is the prediction for the Sub-Concious Self 3.","hiddenpassion":"This is the prediction for the Hidden Passion Number 3.","hpno":"3"}],"success":1}
12-11 08:58:18.811: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 183 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:18.981: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:20.911: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:21.071: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:22.151: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 103 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:22.301: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:22.661: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 79 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:22.972: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:23.721: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:23.951: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:24.242: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:25.291: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:25.601: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:25.761: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:25.912: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:26.881: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:27.163: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:27.451: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:28.322: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:28.551: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:28.711: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:28.872: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:31.291: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:31.591: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:31.813: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:31.971: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:32.131: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:32.761: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:32.981: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:33.251: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:34.721: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:34.881: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:35.041: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:35.212: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:35.351: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:35.482: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:36.492: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:39.071: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:39.321: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:39.611: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:39.981: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:40.271: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:40.572: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:40.801: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:40.971: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:41.151: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:41.481: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:42.571: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:42.861: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:44.141: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:44.291: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:44.831: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:45.021: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:45.201: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 08:58:45.371: I/Choreographer(5133): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main
```

Comment: can you pls format your code and post the stack trace

Comment: when you wrote this code well formatted, you can see lots of errors. One of them is maybe doInBackground has two catch block but the last one is wrong.

Comment: But it is displaying correct values when integers are parsing... but for char only it is not working

Comment: Can you pls post the stack trace

Comment: what is stacktarce ... logcat..?

Comment: Yes but pls well formatted.

Comment: Step-1) `windows => Open perspective => Debug`, Step-2) `Window => Show View => Logcat`

Comment: i uploaded.. the logcat ,, pls check

Comment: @roshanpeter what is the error? i do not see anything in logcat that points to the error? "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." move some heavy work to a thread. But what is the error or problem your are facing. is parsing json your problem?

Comment: Actually ... heere a result is displaying.. but no resut is displaying..I mean ... from server the data can't read...

Comment: nobody here to help me

Comment: You are using JSONObject.getInt. So, only ints will be correctly parsed. If you want to pass 'A', 'B', etc, you should use JSONObject.getString.

Comment: @Salil can you please tell .. where it is... int success9 = json9.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS); if in this code... actually this is to check whether the value is 1 or 0 .. then how we will change it to string..?>

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Ignore my previous comment. Ok, you have not put the real code here because it will not compile as it is, as pointed out by BatuhanC. Anyway, assuming your code compiles, I suggest you print the URL you form using makeHttpRequest. And paste the same URL (with Content-type: application/json, if needed) in the browser to see what response you get. If you get the correct response, then you can zero on the android app logic.

Comment: in logcat cat itself you can see no products found is coming that means the charcter is not parsed.

Answer (score 3):

**CustomHttpClient.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class CustomHttpClient {
/** The time it takes for our client to timeout */
public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds

/** Single instance of our HttpClient */
private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

/**
 * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.
 *
 * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set
 */
private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (mHttpClient == null) {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return mHttpClient;
}

/**
 * Performs an HTTP Post request to the specified url with the
 * specified parameters.
 *
 * @param url The web address to post the request to
 * @param postParameters The parameters to send via the request
 * @return The result of the request
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.
 *
 * @param url The web address to post the request to
 * @return The result of the request
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
        String url=("http://www.avayainfoways.com/hetal/android/index.php?test=" + LeaderBoard.this.test + "&testnm=" +  LeaderBoard.this.testFile);
            //String url=("http://www.avayainfoways.com/hetal/android/index.php?test=MATHS&testnm=Maths_1");
            //response=myuri.toString().trim();
            Log.d("URL",url);
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        //String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
        String jsons = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet(url);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsons);

        if (jsons != null) 
        {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsons);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String test = c.getString(TAG_TEST);
                    String testnm = testname;
                    String score = c.getString(TAG_SCORE);



                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_TEST, test);
                    contact.put(TAG_TESTNM, testnm);
                    contact.put(TAG_SCORE, score+" Marks");

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
   } catch (Exception e)
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally
   {

   }
      return null;
}
```